# Can't figure out whether I need to NEST or JOIN or something else?

Tags: sql, sql-server, relational-database, metabase

I have 3 tables - continents, country info & flights.

I want to run a query that ranks the continents in DESC order by counting the number of countries within them that have 0 flights booked historically. But shows the continents NAME instead of its id

Continents table - cont_id (P-KEY), name varchar, notes varchar

Country table - cntry_id (P-KEY), name varchar, abbreviation varchar

Flights info table - cntry_id int, cont_id int, flights float, date date

I'm doing the on Metabase and thus far I've managed to get it to do everything but show the continents name, it only goes as far as showing its id. I have tried to NEST the main query and tried to using a join instead but neither have worked

```
SELECT "public"."flights_info"."cont_id", count(*) AS "count"
FROM "public"."flights_info"
WHERE "public"."flights_info"."flights" <= 0
GROUP BY "public"."flights_info"."cont_id"
ORDER BY "count" DESC
```

I'm successfully getting the cont_id, I just need a line of code that will make it run a lookup from the continents table and give me names that match the id's (I only want the names to show not the ID's)

Comment: Hint:  `INNER JOIN`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> You can use join or sub-query to do this

Using JOIN

You just need to join with Continents table based cont_id column and fetch Continents name.

```
select Continents.name, count(*) AS "count"
FROM flights_info  flights_info
join Continents Continents 
on Continents.cont_id = flights_info.cont_id
WHERE flights_info.flights <= 0
GROUP BY flights_info.cont_id,Continents.name
ORDER BY "count" DESC
```

Using Sub-Query

You can write another query that give you Continents name by matching cont_id.

```
select (select Continents.name from Continents Continents where Continents.cont_id =                 
flights_info.cont_id ) Continent_name, count(*) AS "count"
FROM flights_info  flights_info
WHERE flights_info.flights <= 0
GROUP BY flights_info.cont_id
ORDER BY "count" DESC
```

Answer (score 1):

So the simple answer is to take your query, reformat it a little, and then add an `INNER JOIN` to the continent table.  Something like this would probably work:

```
SELECT 
    c.[name] AS continent_name,
    COUNT(*) AS [count]
FROM 
    [public].flights_info f
    INNER JOIN [public].continents c ON c.cont_id = f.cont_id
WHERE 
    f.flights <= 0
GROUP BY 
    c.[name]
ORDER BY 
    2 DESC;
```

However, I'm not convinced your original query is correct.  You said you wanted to count the number of countries in each continent with no flights booked historically, and I don't think this is what you are counting at all.  Instead you are counting the number of rows for each continent with a flights value of 0 or less than zero.  Now maybe this is actually how your database works, and if so then cool, the query above should get you onto the right track.

However, if this database works anything like I think it should do then you would need a very different query, e.g. this one:

```
SELECT 
    c.[name] AS continent_name,
    COUNT(DISTINCT cn.cntry_id) AS [count]
FROM 
    [public].continents c
    INNER JOIN [public].country cn ON cn.cont_id = c.cont_id
    LEFT JOIN [public].flights_info f ON f.cont_id = c.cont_id AND f.cntry_id = cn.cntry_id
WHERE 
    ISNULL(f.flights, 0) <= 0
GROUP BY 
    c.[name]
ORDER BY 
    2 DESC;
```

How does this work?  Well it starts off with the continent table, and then links this to countries, to get a list of the countries in each continent.  Then it performs a `LEFT JOIN` to the flights table, so it will get hits even if there's no flight data.  Finally it counts up the number of countries where there was a flights value of 0 or less, or where there's no flights data at all.

Even this probably isn't correct, as if you had two rows for a country (I'm going to assume the flights table has a row for each continent, country, date), where one had a flights = 0 and one had a flights = 10, then this would still report that country as having no flights.  But now I'm getting too far away from the original question I feel...